# Parsing a PHP date within a variable

Tags: php, date, formatting

Right, I'm receiving a date from my mySQL database, the date is saved in a YYYY-MM-DD format, I want to call this as a $date = row['date'] variable and then somehow re-order it in php so that it is a DD-MM-YYYY format instead, I am not sure how I can achieve this though.

Someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = "2010-12-23";
echo date("d-m-Y" , strtotime($date));
```

Comment: But how would i use the date from the SQL database when using that?, sorry i'm a php amateur ):

Comment: You explain it yourself in your question... `$date = row['date']` :-S

Comment: Oh my god D:, I'm sorry I just showed how much of an amateur I actually am lol, best answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_here, "%d-%m-%Y") FROM table_here
```

Comment: Way to go! Always do the maximum using SQL and if really needed, manipulate with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime which is a new class in PHP5.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

```
<?php
    try {
     $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit(1);
    }
    
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
?>
```